# Access: Find partial duplicates, show only one and sum a value

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, duplicates

I have a database for my invoices. I would like to make a form where I list all purchases from one customer. If the customer bought the same item more than once I'd like to show that item only once and sum the quantity field. I'd like to find an SQL solution, but I'm a bit stuck.

This is the query in my form:

```
SELECT Order.fkCustID, Order.OrderID, OrderLine.fkProductID, OrderLine.Qty, ProductList.Item
FROM ProductList INNER JOIN
     ([Order] INNER JOIN
      OrderLine
      ON Order.OrderID = OrderLine.fkOrderID
     ) ON ProductList.ProductID = OrderLine.fkProductID
ORDER BY ProductList.Item;
```

The OrderLine table contains the individual products bought, the Order table links these to my customer table. ProductList contains the product description.

So where fkCustID and fkProductID are the same, I'd like to only show the oldest entry and sum the Qty field of both.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want an aggregation query, that looks something like this:

```
SELECT ol.fkProductID, SUM(ol.Qty) as qty, pl.Item
FROM ProductList as pl INNER JOIN
     ([Order] as o INNER JOIN
      OrderLine as ol
      ON o.OrderID = ol.fkOrderID
     )
     ON pl.ProductID = ol.fkProductID
WHERE o.fkCustID = ???
GROUP BY ol.fkProductID, pl.Item
ORDER BY pl.Item;
```

Comment: Thanks, working like I wanted. If I want to include one extra field from OrderList (ol) in my form, say a set of radio buttons to score the purchase (and both entries in ol are changed when you select the radiobutton), can I link it to this query so that I am able to change the value. Right now it gives me the "recordset can't be changed" error, wich I kind of expected...

Comment: @ArneClicteur . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not comments.  That question seems to have more to do with the application layer than SQL.

Comment: Sorry for asking, tought it was in line with my earlier question. I'm looking at append queries right now, hope it gets me going.

Comment: I also added an extra GROUP BY item on fkCustID to seperate products bought by different customors.

Comment: @ArneClicteur . . . Oddly enough, I removed that `GROUP BY`, because of the `WHERE` clause, but it make a lot of sense.